# Fetching weather data with Javascript(from darksky)

Tags: javascript, geolocation, fetch-api

Hello everyone I am trying to fetch weather api from darksky I have weather class and in its constructor I have defined apikey,city(which I am not using now),long and lat(for coordinations). I want to get browsers geolocation and pass them to long and lat variables . I get an error when I run it saying

"Uncaught ReferenceError: long is not defined" Can you please tell me where is the problem?

```
class Weather {
  constructor() {
    this.apiKey = 'xxxx';
    this.city = city;
    this.long = long;
    this.lat = lat;
  }

  //Fetch from API
  async getWeather() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        clearTimeout(location_timeout);
        this.long = position.coords.longitude;
        this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
      });
      console.log(this.long, this.lat);
      const response = await fetch(`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${this.apiKey}/${this.lat},${this.long}`);
      const responseData = await response.json();
      return responseData.current_observation;
    }
  }

}
const weather = new Weather();

weather.getWeather()
       .then(results => {
         console.log(results);
       })
       .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Is it because of the request url template?
`${this. long}` should not have a space.

Comment: on my code there is no space but i still get the same error,I guess space I have added mistakenly when I copied my code here

Comment: So in your constructor, are long and lat actual decimal values?

Comment: Also you should never post your api key on here. You should probably get a new one.

Comment: These two values are coming from browser depends where the user comes from but yes since they are coordinates they are decimal values

Comment: Ok I covered my api key

Comment: Well when I fill in a value for this.lat and this.long I don't run into that error, so I would look at where ever those are supposed to come from, because I don't think it's working. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VgJOPZ